# Generate abstract class on the fly in .Net

Tags: .net, compilation

I've got an export process which takes an annotated class as an output file definition (much like Linq-To-Entities)

A class looks something like this:

```
<ExportDefinition(Name:="Some Export Format")>
Public Class SomeExportFormat
    Overridable Property Id As Integer

    <DisplayName("Customer Name")>
    Overridable Property CustomerName As String


End Class
```

Properties are overridable as I sometimes have to proxy.

I need to add functionality which allows the specification of transient formats (A WCF call to request export of specific data with a one-time format).

To avoid re-writing a lot of the export code, I'd like to take the definition I'm passed via WCF and define a new class.

Is my best bet to use `System.CodeDom.Compiler` or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd be looking at `TypeBuilder`, but I'm a little bit... *unbalanced*, and ready to hop into `ILGenerator`. But yes, You can create new subclasses that way. Watch out, though - WCF and EF won't automatically accept your types. Most inheritance-aware libraries (which includes WCF and EF) will *hate* dynamic subclasses, since they weren't expecting them and will treat them as completely unexpected data.

Comment: Thanks Marc, about the only code that will ever touch it should be my own (I'm using reflection to extract various properties and attributes then using that info to format lines). I'll have a play and see how it goes

Comment: Ok, having read through some articles, it seems like creating a class and properties would be quite verbose (I have to know how things work and I've been meaning to learn more about IL so this might be a good opportunity). Can you explain why you'd go that route rather than `CodeDom.Compiler`?

Comment: @Basic maybe I'm biased, but that is what "clicks" for me. If codedom clicks for you, then great. Other factors: I love DynamicMethod, which is IlGenerator based, and I work on a range of platforms - reflection.emit has better overall support than codedom

Comment: I completely understand - There are some slightly obscure things I do that work well for me. I'll have to do some more reading to get it in-depth but thanks you, I think you've given a good answer. I'll leave this open a few days in case any more brilliant ideas arrive.